# How to add mapping via go-elasticsearch package

Tags: go, elasticsearch

Basically when I am trying to insert a new document to non-existing index, it is automatically sets to dynamic mapping.
But I have issues where in sometimes  I want to change the data type of the fields on the ES.

I want to set it via my go-lang service but looks like go-elasticsearch package doesn't support it? correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ElasticSearch Typed API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/go-api/current/typedapi.html)

To **create an index**

```go
    client := GetTypedClient()

    // create index if not exists
    index := "index_name"
    if !isIndexExists(GetClient(), index) {
        res, err := client.Indices.Create(getIndexName(index)).Do(context.Background())
        if err != nil {
            ...
        }
    }
```

And **put mapping** as well

```go
    // update mapping
    memoryMapping := types.NewNestedProperty()
    memoryMapping.Properties = map[string]types.Property{
        "total": types.NewIntegerNumberProperty(),
        "free":  types.NewIntegerNumberProperty(),
        "used":  types.NewIntegerNumberProperty(),
    }

    uptimeMapping := types.NewNestedProperty()
    uptimeMapping.Properties = map[string]types.Property{
        "app": types.NewIntegerNumberProperty(),
        "os":  types.NewIntegerNumberProperty(),
    }

    loadMapping := types.NewNestedProperty()
    loadMapping.Properties = map[string]types.Property{
        "avg1":  types.NewFloatNumberProperty(),
        "avg5":  types.NewFloatNumberProperty(),
        "avg15": types.NewFloatNumberProperty(),
    }

    res, err := client.Indices.PutMapping(index).
        Request(&putmapping.Request{
            Properties: map[string]types.Property{
                "createdAt": types.NewDateProperty(),
                "memory":    memoryMapping,
                "uptime":    uptimeMapping,
                "load":      loadMapping,
            },
        }).
        Do(context.Background())

    if err != nil {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an index along with its mapping using go-elasticsearch/esapi [go-elasticsearch/esapi](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/esapi#IndicesCreateRequest)

Create a request as below:

```
mapping := `{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 1
      },
      "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "message": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
        }
}`

// Index - pass index name
// Body - pass mapping, settings etc
indexReq := esapi.IndicesCreateRequest{
    Index: "my-index",
    Body: strings.NewReader(string(mapping)),
}

resp, err := indexReq.Do(ctx, elasticclient)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

by this way you can create a new index with specific mapping

Comment: Thank you so much. You are such a blessing

Comment: Always welcome. Lets keep growing by helping each other